# SyncResponse which jar is needed to create the device

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.DisconnectRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.ExecuteRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.ExecuteResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.QueryRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.QueryResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SmartHomeApp;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncRequest;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse;
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload;


public class GoogleDeviceSync extends SmartHomeApp {
    
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public SyncResponse onSync(@NotNull SyncRequest syncRequest, @Nullable Map<?, ?> map) {
      Payload payload = new Payload();
      payload.setAgentUserId("1836.15267389");
      payload.setDevices(
          new Device[] {
            new Device.Builder()
                .setId("123")
                .setType("action.devices.types.OUTLET")
                .addTrait("action.devices.traits.OnOff")
                .setName(
                    Collections.singletonList("My Outlet 1234"),
                    "Night light",
                    Collections.singletonList("Wall plug"))
                .setWillReportState(true)
                .setDeviceInfo("lights-out-inc", "hs1234", "3.2", "11.4")
                .setCustomData(
                    new JSONObject()
                        .put("fooValue", 74)
                        .put("barValue", true)
                        .put("bazValue", "foo"))
                .build(),
            new Device.Builder()
                .setId("456")
                .setType("action.devices.types.LIGHT")
                .addTrait("action.devices.traits.OnOff")
                .addTrait("action.devices.traits.Brightness")
                .addTrait("action.devices.traits.ColorTemperature")
                .addTrait("action.devices.traits.ColorSpectrum")
                .setName(
                    Collections.singletonList("Lights Out Inc. bulb A19 color hyperglow"),
                    "Lamp",
                    Collections.singletonList("Reading lamp"))
                .setWillReportState(true)
                .setDeviceInfo("Lights Out Inc.", "hg11", "1.2", "5.4")
                .setCustomData(
                    new JSONObject()
                        .put("fooValue", 12)
                        .put("barValue", false)
                        .put("bazValue", "bar"))
                .build(),
          });
      return new SyncResponse(syncRequest.getRequestId(), payload);
    }   
}
```

Which jar is `payload.setDevices(new Device[])` and `Device` introduced from?
From the https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents document, there is only code, and the introduction of jar is not shown. So which jar does'device' need to introduce

Answer (score 0):

**Adding dependencies (jars)**

The dependency (the jar) that needs to be added in the `gradle.build` should be:

```
implementation 'com.google.actions:actions-on-google:1.8.0'
```

The specific version will depend on your configuration and environment.
You can see a full example [gradle.build](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-java/blob/master/build.gradle). In the same folder there are also other configuration examples.

**Importing Classes**

I also add some information on where the `Payload` and `Device` classes are.
[Payload](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-java/com/google/actions/api/smarthome/SyncResponse.Payload.html) is nested inside `SyncResponse` and [Device](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-java/com/google/actions/api/smarthome/Payload.Device.html) is nested inside `Payload`.

`Payload` is imported with the following import statement:

```
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload
```

`Device` can be imported with the following import statement:

```
import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload.Device
```

**Creating Objects**

To create a new Payload from the Payload in the SyncResponse:

```
new SyncResponse.Payload()
```

And you can try to create a Device from its builder:

```
SyncResponse.Payload.Device.Builder deviceBuilder = new syncResponse.Payload.Device.Builder()
```

See this [example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/MySmartHomeApp.java) for usage of the 'Payload' and 'Device'.

Comment: import com.google.actions.api.smarthome.SyncResponse.Payload.Device。Importing this will give an error

Comment: What kind of error? There should be a static Device class enclosed inside Payload. I updated the answer with the docs. The error might help find the issue. Also your dependencies might help.